# How to avoid duplicate rquests with jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Here I have one requirement with AJAX and I gave one `url(UpdateURL)` to the `url param.` In success case I'm going to call one `dataTable(called loadGrid()),` 
here I need to call same `url(UpdateURL)` to the `loadGrid()`, meanwhile I'm calling two times same `url(UpdateURL)`, it causes duplicate requests.
Can any one help me how to use `url(UpdateURL)` single time and avoiding duplicate requests. Sorry for the confusion.
Here is my code,

```
$("#UploadButton").click(function(){ 
$("#idLoading").show();     
          var UpdateURL="some url"; 
          $.ajax({ 
          type: "post", 
          url: UpdateURL,     // calling first time  
          dataType: "json", 
          cache : false, 
          success: function(response) {         
            loadGrid(UpdateURL);  // calling second time
            $("#idLoading").hide(); 
          }, 
          error: function (xhr, status) {   
                     $("#idLoading").show();
                     timeout_trigger();
          }    
       });  
  });  

function loadGrid(url){
    $.getJSON(url,function (output)
    {
        try
        {
          var pdlJsonObj = output.aaData;               
                  var tdata  = $("#IdDatatble").dataTable({
                        "aaData": pdlJsonObj,
                        "bDestroy": true,   
                        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",                                     
                        "aaSorting": [],                                    
            "fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull)
                            {                           
                            $(nRow).attr('id', iDisplayIndex);
                            },
             "fnInitComplete": function ()
                            {                           
                           $("#IdDatatble tbody tr:eq(0)").find('td').each(function () { });
                    }
            });
        }

        catch(err)
        {
            alert(err.message);
        }       

    });
}
```

Comment: What is this code doing? ie what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Why not save the response data in a global variable and make it available to both functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't understand why you need to call a ajax and a getJson for the same thing, try this:

```
$("#UploadButton").click(function(){
    var UpdateURL="some url"; 
    $("#idLoading").show();     
    loadGrid(UpdateURL);
});  

function loadGrid(url){
    $.getJSON(url,function (output)
    {
        try
        {
          var pdlJsonObj = output.aaData;               
                  var tdata  = $("#IdDatatble").dataTable({
                        "aaData": pdlJsonObj,
                        "bDestroy": true,   
                        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",                                     
                        "aaSorting": [],                                    
            "fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull)
                            {                           
                            $(nRow).attr('id', iDisplayIndex);
                            },
             "fnInitComplete": function ()
                            {                           
                           $("#IdDatatble tbody tr:eq(0)").find('td').each(function () { });
                    }
            });
        }

        catch(err)
        {
            alert(err.message);
        }       

    }).done(function( json ) {
        $("#idLoading").hide(); 
    })
    .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
        $("#idLoading").show();
        timeout_trigger();
    });
}
```